# Is there a way to programmatically give items to a single player character?

Tags: terraria

I'm not normally one for cheat codes, but my son was playing with my Terraria character on his own the other day, and accidentally threw away several items that I had worked hard to obtain.  Is there an easy way to assign those items back to my character?

Comment: I'd recommend using [TerrariViewer](http://terrariviewer.codeplex.com/) to edit your inventory.

Comment: @Fambida That's what I was going to recommend.  Post it as an answer so I can upvote you! :)

Comment: Just be careful with any character editor because if you are not careful you can end up destroying even more items and cause more problems. I recommend putting everything in a couple of chests and then using an editor just to be safe!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[TerrariViewer](http://terrariviewer.codeplex.com/) is the best character editor I've used for the game (and I am one for cheat codes)

Answer (score 0):

If your lucky, you can find certain T-Shock servers that give you access for /i which give you the item of your choice.They can be hard to come by though, I just randomly stumbled on one. The best option would be through InvEdit or a editor for terraira.

Answer (score 0):

Every now and then I need to play referee when my kids jump onto each others' worlds and fight over certain items. When I find that they're arguing over something small, like golden chests or a stack of material, I usually jump onto a map that I have downloaded, [Builders Workshop](http://www.curse.com/maps/terraria/builders-workshop). I'd recommend poking through there to see if you need to restore lost items.

Answer (score 0):

On the iPad, there is a built-in editor.  If you are playing the game and press pause then repeatedly press the far top left corner of the screen the dev editor comes up. Press the top angler fish button.

Go to [this](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Item_ids) link and press expand on the first two expand buttons. Vanilla Terraria only has ids up to 621. Find an item id, then go back to Terraria and type item (item id) and it will give you the item.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Terrasavr](http://yal.cc/r/terrasavr/fl/).

It doesn't require a download because it is online based.

Comment: What makes it better over other options presented here?

Comment: @Robotnik `It doesn't require a download` isn't that cool enough? :D

Comment: @Nitro.de - I know, I was trying to prompt OP into turning an OK answer into a great answer :). Does it have different features? Are the tools it provides easier to use? that sort of thing